# Reorder an itemize

Tags: itemize

For example, can I assign 2) to item 2 and 1) to item 1?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item item 2
\item item 1
\end{itemize}
```

I want reorder an `itemize`, can I do it? Can I assign a position to any item?

Any suggestion? Thanks!!

Comment: `itemize` does not, by default number its items.  Do you mean `enumerate`, which does number its items?  And if so, an optional argument `\item [2)] item 2 \item[1)] item 1` allows the natural numbering to be overridden.

Comment: Of course, assigning a label does not re-*order* the items, it only renumbers them (perhaps out of natural order).  Are you actually asking for the second `\item` to appear 1st in the document?

Answer (score 2):

Is a reversed `enumerate` environment the solution? I don't know, but the `etaremune` provides this. Please remember to compile twice!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etaremune}
\begin{document}

\begin{etaremune}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \item is
  \item nice
\end{etaremune}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Like this?  However, since there is a missing list environment, LaTeX will complain "lonely \item".

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\item2. item 2
\item1. item 1
\item5. item 6

\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX will complain because this is incorrect. `\item`s belong in a list environment, and the correct way of changing the label is to enclose the new label in square brackets. See the comment by Steven B. Segletes to the OP's question.

Comment: @erik it is an incorrect answer with reference to the latex list environment.   Notwithstanding hurting the items feelings, I think it gets done what the OP was asking for.  But I don't know, are there any adverse effects other than the "lonely" log entry that makes this a bad answer?

Comment: By doing this, structure and content are no longer separate. For example, what if you want to modify list appearance with something like `enumitem`? The settings won't apply to your orphaned `\item`s. This is like aligning things into columns using `\hspace` or a bunch of `\ ` when a table environment would be a much better approach.

Comment: @erik ok, I understand your point of view. Thanks for explaining yourself.